# Cognito IDToken Renewal using RefreshToken

Tags: android, authentication, amazon-cognito, refresh-token

Hi I am android application developer , I am using cognito authentication mechanism for mobile app. Once i authenticate my user i get `RefreshToken` and `IDToken`. According to Amazon cognito it expire `IDToken` after exactly one hour.I am trying to get my session again to get token again and here is how i am trying to get it done.

```
    String poolId       = 'xxxxxx';
    String clientId     = 'xxxxxx';
    String clientSecret = 'xxxxxx';

    CognitoUserPool userPool = new CognitoUserPool(context, poolId, clientId, clientSecret,Regions.EU_WEST_1);
    CognitoUser user = userPool.getUser();

    user.getSessionInBackground(new AuthenticationHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(CognitoUserSession userSession, CognitoDevice newDevice) {
            String idToken = userSession.getIdToken().getJWTToken();

            Map<String, String> logins = new HashMap<String, String>();
            logins.put("cognito-idp." + Constants.REGION + ".amazonaws.com/" + Constants.UserPool, userSession.getIdToken().getJWTToken());

            credentialsProvider.setLogins(logins);
            credentialsProvider.refresh();
        }

        @Override
        public void getAuthenticationDetails(AuthenticationContinuation authenticationContinuation, String userId) {
            Log.i("MQTT","Detail");
        }

        @Override
        public void getMFACode(MultiFactorAuthenticationContinuation continuation) {
            Log.i("MQTT","MFACode");
        }

        @Override
        public void authenticationChallenge(ChallengeContinuation continuation) {
            Log.i("MQTT","Challenge");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Exception exception) {
            Log.i("MQTT","Fail");
        }
    });
```

I have `userpoolid` and need to know where from i can get `clientID` and `clientSecret`.So that i get data in `onSuccess` callback and get `IDToken`.

Really thankful if someone can help out.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- Go to your user pool in cognito and click on the pool you want to
  work on.
- Under general settings, click on app clients.
- Now click on add app client.
- Give your app a name
- Make sure the **Generate client secret** is selected.
- Click on create client app.

Now you can note down the client id and client secret.

Docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-client-apps.html